# Android ImageView: Running Different ImageViews with time intervals

Tags: android, imageview

I'm trying to make an activity where i have a **button** and **three imageview(imgv1,imgv2,imgv3)**. after i clicked the button, the first imagview(imgv1) will appear. and after 2secs, the second imageview(img2) will appear for 2secs and third imageview(imgv3) for 2secs.

here's a piece of code that i'm working for using handler.

```
     final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    img2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }, 2000);


        }
    });
```

now i can only run 2 imageviews and i don't know how to run the third image.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:src="@drawable/wh1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/image2"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/wh2" />

 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/image2"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/wh2" />
```

in my xml file here i set my three imageview visibility gone, so they can only be visible when the button is clicked.

please help me if someone has any code example. i've seen many post about this in a single ImageView changing image resources, but this is different from that so please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `int`name **count** in your `Activity`. Then you could do something like that:

```
 final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            count = 0;
            final ImageView[] images = {(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1), (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2), (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image3)};
            v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    images[count].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    switch (count){
                        case 0:
                            images[1].setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            images[2].setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            images[0].setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            images[2].setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            images[0].setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            images[1].setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            break;
                    }
                    count++;
                    if (count == 2)
                        v.removeCallbacks(this);
                    else
                        v.postDelayed(this, 2000);

                }
            }, 2000);


        }
    });
```

Comment: Try now, I forgot the postDelayed inside the run() method.

Comment: it works!, thank you sir, but i want to stop when it reached the third image

Comment: i change count>2 , third image doesn't show if the condition is true with count==2, thank you sir! :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of setting visibility of 3 Image views you can use single imageView and change the content of imageView by using `setImageResource()` method or `setImageBitmap()` or `setImageDrawable()` method.

Comment: yea i've seen a lot of post about changing content. but i want is to change different imagviews, i'm planning to put audio as well per imagviews. thanks